# How can I add "root" privileges in LxPanel launcher?

Tags: launcher, lubuntu, lxde, lxpanel

how can I add "root" privileges in LxPanel launcher (in Lubuntu)? I would like have launcher for Synaptic, but Synaptic need root privileges.

Have anyone any idea how it do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You can achieve this without needing to install any extra packages.

1. Add your application (synaptic) to the panel
2. Open a `lxterminal` and navigate to `~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels`
3. type the following to open the file `leafpad panel`
4. find the line `id=/usr/share/applications/synaptic.desktop`
5. change this line to `id=synaptic.desktop`
6. save and exit leafpad
7. create a local applications menu folder `mkdir -p ~/.local/share/applications`
8. copy the master synaptic.desktop file: `cp /usr/share/applications/synaptic.desktop ~/.local/share/applications`
9. edit the newly copied file: `leafpad ~/.local/share/applications/synaptic.desktop`
10. find the line `Exec=synaptic-pkexec`
11. change this to `Exec=gksudo synaptic-pkexec`
12. save, exit leafpad, logout and login.

Answer (score 1):

Graphical option -

Try [LxMenuEditor](http://opendesktop.org/content/show.php?content=138298) Add in a custom command `gksu nautilus` or `gksu synaptic`

Sereenshots (I did not add them directly as they are large)

http://forum.lxde.org/download/file.php?id=262

http://forum.lxde.org/download/file.php?id=263

To install the dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install lxshortcut zenity
```

LxMenuEditor itself is a script, save it in ~/bin

```
mkdir ~/bin
cd bin
wget http://opendesktop.org/CONTENT/content-files/138298-LxMenuEditor
mv 138298-LxMenuEditor LxMenuEditor
chmod a+x LxMenuEditor
```

to run it manually, `~/bin/LxMenuEditor`

Once you log out and log back in, ~/bin will be on your path and you can either make a menu entry of it or open a terminal and type `LxMenuEditor`

Your other option is to manually edit your menu or write a launcher. Writing a launcher is not too hard , they are located in `/usr/share/applications` as *.desktop files. You can use most any .desktop as a template, just set an icon and use `gksu synaptic` as the action / command.

For details, see

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LXDE#Application_Menu_Editing

http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/